# Early 2006 macbook pro. Core duo

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a early 06 macbook pro. My osx crashed on me a few days ago after installing firefox. Dnow it freezes right before login. So I figure it is time to make it a Linux machine.  Any specific steps for installing on an original macbook pro?

Comment: You may be interested in this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook1-1/Hardy

Comment: Check this article from the community: [How to install Ubuntu on MacBook using USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)

Answer (score 0):

I've been attempting the same thing for a while now, and be warned that there are no proprietary drivers for the Radeon card, and the open source drivers run it extremely hot, even at idle. Also the sound won't work out of the box. Slackware-based distros seem to work best with the 2006 mbp's hardware, at least in my experience. Best of luck!

Oh, and to get Linux booted on the machine, I strongly recommend the rEFInd boot menu. Installs in a second, and makes everything easier.